# looking for an old game it had a battery operated ball

Tags: identify-this-game

It was a game almost like kerplunk but it was a ball that moved around in a change and you had to take turns removing stickes to the cage till the ball got free

Comment: What do you mean by "moved around in a change"?

Comment: @Joe Contextually, change may be "cage."